# How to handle a fixed width flat file row width change in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

For example now I have flat file with row width (length) 100 next day I got file with row width change to 105 and other next day row width change 125. In this case how build SSIS package?

Files :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a sample of the file and let us know what SSIS version is going to be used to process it.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like a fixed-width file. Unless it's the final column _and_ there is a row delimiter instead of a true fixed-width file. As Jayvee requests post a sample of the file from day 1 (100) and and day 3 (125 char)

Comment: sample files update just now
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 14.0.1000.169

Comment: Ok, it is not a length problem is that some days not all the fields are populated

Comment: Do you need those extra column further down the line or can you ignore them?

Comment: need new extra add line as per new column but not consider column name

Comment: @Chris  do you have any hint how to handle this situation?
every time have to change etl for new coming extra column 
can't set the some variable to hold new extra columns ?

Comment: @user17084213 Using the answer provided by Jayvee is the strategy I would employ if I had to use SSIS for this task. If you are not stuck using SSIS I would suggest using Azure Data Factory. It can handle schema drift like this with little effort.

Comment: @Chris you have demo about this issue solve in Azure Data Factory ?

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is read the flat file as one column with the longest possible width and then separate into columns via Derived Column. In this way if there are missing column they will simply be set as nulls. Your data flow would be:

[image: SUBSTRING(AllColumns,101,50)]

your connection manager:

[image]

Flat File Source:

[image]

Derived column transformation:
(this is just an example, you may need to work out the actual start/length of the columns for the substrings)

[image]

Comment: Thank you got it ...
there other way to create dynamic process ?

Comment: The other way would be a C# script component. That would allow to manipulate the input as needed.

Comment: Do you mean i need to wrote C# script for achieve this one? or can make SP with xml path using Layout Definition

Comment: You can do it by SP too, sure thing, I was mentioning a script component as the other options, if you wanted to do it within the SSIS environment